# What does database 0 means in laravel configuration file for redis

Tags: laravel, redis

In `app/config/database.php` on Laravel, I see :

```
'redis' => array(

    'cluster' => false,

    'default' => array(
        'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
        'port'     => 6379,
        'database' => 0,
    ),

),
```

What does `'database' => 0` means ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means php will use the 0th redis database.

By default, there are 16 redis databases, and 0th database is the default database we use.

You can see the configurations in redis.conf.